# Как вывести повторяющиеся части строки Python, а так же ее самую длинную повторяющуюся часть и остальные повторяющиеся части

Tags: python

Мы хотим вывести повторяющийся кусок входящей на ввод строки (без разделителей).

Например, на ввод берем текст книги повторенный N раз. Нужно найти уникальный кусок текста книги в тексте без повторений.

Исходные данные:
1234123123121211

Результат:
1234 - самые длинные данные
123, 12, 11 - другие повторяющиеся данные

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Плохо поставлена задача. Вся книга и есть кусок без повторений. Найдите любой символ, который встречается больше одного раза - этот символ и есть кусок, который повторяется. Чем не ответы?

Answer (score 0):

1. считываем несколько символов в piece, их количество задано в repeating_length_min, с 0 индекса строки data
2. если строка piece есть внутри строки data, то положим ее в лист repeating_pieces
3. считываем несколько символов в piece, их количество задано в repeating_length_min, с 1 индекса строки data
4. если строка piece есть внутри строки data, то положим ее в лист repeating_pieces

.... Повторяем эти шаги, пока не дойдем до индекса data[data_len-repeating_length_min-1], этот индекс включается в проверку

5. считываем несколько символов в piece, их количество задано в repeating_length_min + 1, с 0 индекса строки data
6. если строка piece есть внутри строки data, то положим ее в лист repeating_pieces
7. считываем несколько символов в piece, их количество задано в repeating_length_min +1, с 1 индекса строки data
8. если строка piece есть внутри строки data, то положим ее в лист repeating_pieces

.... Делаем это до тех пор, пока repeating_length_min + N не станет равным data_len

.... Теперь в списке repeating_pieces собраным все повторяющиеся подстроки строки data

9. сортируем список, что бы наверху (в 0 индексе) были самые длинные строки: repeating_pieces.sort(key=len)
10. выводим с помощью print в цикле сперва самую длинную строку из списка repeating_pieces
11. а затем выводим с помощью print в цикле все остальные строки из списка repeating_pieces

Code:

```html
data = input("Введите данные для анализа:\n")
data_len = len(data)
repeating_length_min = input("Задайте минимальную длину строки для анализа совпадений:\n")
repeating_length_min = int(repeating_length_min)
repeating_pieces = []
longest_repeating_piece = ''
piece = ''
index_counter = 0
range_counter = 0

while range_counter != data_len - repeating_length_min:
    while index_counter <= data_len - repeating_length_min:
        for i in range(repeating_length_min + range_counter):
            piece += data[i]
        if piece in data:
            repeating_pieces.append(piece)
        piece = ''
        index_counter += 1
    index_counter = 0
    range_counter += 1

repeating_pieces.sort(key=len)
print(f'\nСамое короткое повторяющееся значение: {repeating_pieces[0]}')
print(f'\nСамое длинное повторяющееся значение: {repeating_pieces[-1]}')
print('\nТоп 10 самых коротких повторяющихся значений:')

for i in range(10):
    print(f'#{i}: {repeating_pieces[i]}')

repeating_pieces.reverse()
print('\nТоп 10 самых длинных повторяющихся значений:')

for i in range(10):
    print(f'#{i}: {repeating_pieces[i]}')
```